# How to select data from multiple row into one row with multiple column dynamically?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to select multiple rows of data into one row through multiple columns which will change dynamically.

This is in Oracle database. I want to count repeated work done by the LEAD_TECHNISIAN_ID within a duration. If the difference of last work delivery date and new work receive date is 15 or below 15 then LEAD_TECHNISIAN_ID  has one repeated work.

1. List item

```
SELECT *
FROM (WITH CTE AS (  
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RW,
           RECEIVED_DATE,
           DELIVERY_DATE,
           SERVICE_NO,
           LEAD_TECHNISIAN_ID,
           ID,
           SERVICE_CENTER
    FROM (  SELECT cc.SERVICE_CENTER,
                   CC.ID,
                   CC.BARCODE,
                   TRUNC (cc.CREATED_DATE) RECEIVED_DATE,
                   TRUNC (CC.DELIVERY_DATE) DELIVERY_DATE,
                   cc.SERVICE_NO,
                   CC.LEAD_TECHNISIAN_ID
            FROM customer_complains cc
            WHERE cc.BARCODE IN (SELECT BARCODE
                                 FROM (SELECT BARCODE,
                                              COUNT (BARCODE)
                                        FROM customer_complains c
                                        WHERE c.BARCODE <> 'UNDEFINE'
                                        AND C.BARCODE = NVL ('351950102757821', BARCODE)
                                        AND c.SEGMENT3 = NVL ('',c.SEGMENT3)
                                        AND c.SEGMENT3 IN (SELECT SEGMENT3
                                                           FROM ITEM_MST
                                                            WHERE PRODUCT_GROUP = NVL ('',PRODUCT_GROUP))
                                        GROUP BY c.BARCODE
                                        HAVING COUNT (c.BARCODE) >1))
                                   ORDER BY ID DESC)
                  ORDER BY ID DESC)
    SELECT a.id,
           a.DELIVERY_DATE,
           a.RECEIVED_DATE,
           b.RECEIVED_DATE PRE_RCV,
           b.DELIVERY_DATE PRE_DEL,
           (a.RECEIVED_DATE - b.DELIVERY_DATE) AS DIFF,
           a.SERVICE_NO,
           a.LEAD_TECHNISIAN_ID,
           b.LEAD_TECHNISIAN_ID PRE_TECH               --, a.DELIVERY_DATE
    FROM CTE a 
         LEFT JOIN CTE b ON a.RW = b.RW + 1
    )
WHERE DIFF <= 15
```

Here is the output for a specific barcode. but when I try for All the barcode I have in My Customer_complains table. The query provides irrelevant output.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your code is giving numbers 1,2,3,4... to rows irrespective of `LEAD_TECHNISIAN_ID` and then you are joining it with `RW`. It will not consider `LEAD_TECHNISIAN_ID` while giving row numbers.

`RW` must start with 1 for each `LEAD_TECHNISIAN_ID`.

You just need to change calculation of `RW` as following:

```
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY LEAD_TECHNISIAN_ID ORDER BY ID) AS RW
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I think currently my code is giving number 1,2,3,4....... rows. I need to partition it Based on BARCODE.

Comment: I think currently my code is giving number 1,2,3,4....... rows. I need to partition it Based on BARCODE. I actually need to find the total number of " how much The BARCODE is repeated for a LEAD_TECHNISIAN_ID within 15 days from previously delivered

Comment: Ok, then you can just replace `LEAD_TECHNISIAN_ID` with `BARCODE` in `PARTITION BY` clause